# Applications that run on Mono in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mono

I think Mono, and the C# language, are a great, nay, fantastic project.

My question is: how prevalent is Mono in Ubuntu? How much of a penetration is it getting, and what applications run on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a good number of programs that use mono in Ubuntu if you look at the whole repository.  In the default install, I believe the following are the only mono apps:

- f-spot
- gbrainy
- tomboy

There may be more, I just made this list from looking at which applications would be removed if I removed libmono*. However, even just having these means that a good portion of the mono framework is installed by default which makes it very easy to deploy mono apps onto Ubuntu.  A few very popular Ubuntu applications are written in mono, including gnome-do, Banshee, and docky.  The trend I've seen from the sidelines is that despite its detractors, mono is gaining a lot of ground with Desktop application authors because of the speed at one can develop fairly rich GUI apps with the monodevelop IDE.

Comment: f-spot will be replace by shotwell (written in vala) in the up-coming 10.10 default install.

Comment: Banshee is now the default audio player on Ubuntu - but I wouldn't use it as an example of anything - it frequently crashes and I've heard a lot of bad things about it.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Steven's list, [Gnome Do](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/gnome-do), [Beagle](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/beagle).